# Promises, make available on watch, angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with understanding promises.

```
  $scope.$watch('selectedPipe', function() {
    $scope.sizesFromPipes = test.getSizes($scope.selectedPipe.pipe_id);

    $scope.sizesFromPipes.then(function(sizes){
      $scope.selectedSize = sizes[0]; //Working
      $scope.calculationResults = CalculationFactory.mainCalculation(sizes); 
      console.log($scope.calculationResults) //Working
    });
    console.log($scope.calculationResults) //Is not getting updated, binded view is not getting updated either. 
  });
```

I have a view that listens on calculationResults. It works once when the app is loaded. But it's not getting updated outside when the watch triggers. How do I make calculationResults update "outside" so my view can access it?

Comment: try logging within `then`, can't access data until promise is resolved

Comment: Logging within works fine.

Comment: angular will update DOm when the data that is in expressions in markup changes

Comment: not true...post demo that replicates your problem

Answer (score 1):

A promise runs asyncronously, so your console output will fire before the promise actually finishes.

Here is a quick example showing the timing of a promise and properties being set on the `$scope`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/NNgw6/

### Update:

I've created [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/NNgw6/7/) to try and show promises resolving at different times and how that shows up in the bindings.

Comment: So it's not possible to bind a view to a promise?

Comment: @user1572526 - I'm not sure what you mean. In this case you aren't binding to a promise, you are simply setting a property on your view. Unless `CalculationFactory.mainCalculation(sizes)` is returning a promise. What I am saying is that it is a timing issue. Your console statement is going to fire before your promise finishes and therefore will always have the old value.

Comment: Thx! I look into it tonight. I'll mark your answear if I manage to figure it out =)